# Implementing SSO into Joomla 3 to gain access to the website

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, single-sign-on, intranet, google-sso

I have been asked to create an internal intranet. One of their criteria is to allow employees to access the site using Google SSO. This isn't to log into the backend, it is purely to gain access to the site.

I am creating it in Joomla 3. Can anyone advise how I would go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is adding Joomla SAML capabilities. There is a Joomla3.3 SAML plugin [1] that you can use to connect with Google (Google will act as Identity Provider) [2]

Then you may add SAML to the rest of the intranet's apps.

[1] https://github.com/onelogin/joomla-saml

[2] https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en