# Add Google SSO to view certain pages and download documents on intranet built in joomla

Tags: security, joomla, intranet, google-sso

I'm building a company intranet in Joomla 3.0 and need a way that when people try and access the policy documents, they have to be signed in ideally using SSO.

Can anyone suggest how I do this please?

Comment: Have you Googled e.g. `joomla Google SSO`? There seem to be plenty of resources there.

Comment: Also you seem to have asked the very same question before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441197/implementing-sso-into-joomla-3-to-gain-access-to-the-website